# Causal Mediation Analysis - Negative indirect and total effect, positive direct effect

Tags: r, modeling, interpretation, mediation

I'm running a causal mediation analysis with the `mediation` package in R. My summary table looks like this:

```
Causal Mediation Analysis 

Nonparametric Bootstrap Confidence Intervals with the BCa Method

               Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value
ACME           -0.07842     -0.08679     -0.07051    0.00
ADE             0.00902     -0.00403      0.02235    0.17
Total Effect   -0.06940     -0.08124     -0.05697    0.00
Prop. Mediated  1.12994      0.96084      1.40458    0.00

Sample Size Used: 3000 

Simulations: 10000
```

Normally I would interpret this to say that of the estimated total effect (-0.060) of the IV on the DV (as the IV increases, the DV decreases), an estimated -.077 is due to the Mediator, and the remaining .017 is due to the IV itself. What's confusing is that the mediation effect seems to be more strongly negative than the total effect, and so the interpretation is confusing. It would be easier to interpret of the signs were all the same. Can anyone help me to clarify this?

Comment: Your output suggests that you are using bootstrap 95% confidence intervals for the parameters.  The BCa method is one of the better nonparametric bootstrap methods that adjusts the endpoints using a bias adjustment and what Efron calls an acceleration constant.  I am not sure why it is used for your causal mediation analysis.

Comment: I've been using Hayes' Mediation, Moderation, and Conditional Process Analysis as my guide. I'm not really sure why I would NOT use the bca method. I'm also not sure how that would affect the nature of my question. Regardless, I'm rerunning with percentage instead of bda, just to see how it differs.

Comment: I didn't say that you shouldn't.  I am just not familiar with the type of analysis you are applying.

Comment: It's similar in principal to the Baron-Kenny procedure. There is a mediation effect (ACME above), a Direct effect (ADE), and a total effect. in this case, the total effect is the sum of the Direct and mediation effects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In mediation analysis, whatever the estimation procedure, it is totally fine to obtain direct and indirect effects with opposite directions. This situation is sometimes referred to as "inconsistent mediation", as it produces one between direct or indirect effect to be larger than the total effect (see here for further details: MacKinnon, David P., Amanda J. Fairchild, and Matthew S. Fritz. "Mediation analysis." Annu. Rev. Psychol. 58 (2007): 593-614.).

The interpretation of your output is that the negative effect of the exposure on the outcome is completely due to the indirect mechanism operating through your mediator. Direct pathways (those not including the mediator) are in the opposite direction, but these are not strong enough to cancel out the negative effect of indirect pathways.

In such case, the common proportion measures (for example the proportion mediated) are not meaningful.

Comment: Thanks so much for your thoughtful (and cited) answer! After discussing with a colleague I may go with a somewhat modified model, that looks at the moderation, rather than mediation (or possibly a combination of both).